# How can I calculate the radius of a residue?

Tags: proteins, protein-folding

I want to read a PDB file and display/render the atoms using a graphics engine.

If I consider each residue in the protein file as a solid sphere, what would be the radius of the sphere?

How can I calculate it? Or, is there any database for that?

Comment: Will you solely use the radius to display the residues as balls? Or do you want to use them to compute other quantities (e.g. the approximate total volume of the protein, or the parameters of a coarse-grained model) as well? Different purposes may probably require different radii, even for the same residue.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I don't foresee anyone answering this if the questions in wzkchem5's most recent comment get ignored.